# regex. how to exclude a substring from the result after it matches the pattern

Tags: regex

I wonder how i can exclude a substring from the result after it matches the pattern.
example:

```
<a href="?page1"><?php __('string1');?></a>
<a href="?page2"><?php __("string2");?></a>
```

I want to get only the strings passed as parameters to the __() function. i tried this regex:

```
'/__\(((\'([^\']+)\')|(\"([^\"]+)\"))/'
```

but that returns 'string1' and "string2" wrapped in single quotes and double quotations.
how can i exclude single quotes and double quotations?

Comment: I was talking privately with @ahmedhelmy007 about the problem, we found another solution which is to use the token_get_all() function in php. this is more accurate than regex and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
'/__\(('|")([^\1]+)\1\)/'
       ^1^  ^^2^^^
```

You can see it [online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tp0k)

Every time when you open a round bracket you create a capturing group. So, if you don't want it use `(?:)` this would define a non capturing group. I don't use this here. I rewrote your regex a bit. In my first group I check if there are `'` or `"` and store them into group 1. later on I use the backreference `\1` to this group one, to use the correct character.

Your result is then stored always into group 2. How you access this result depends on your used language.

Comment: @stema,
your regex is very powerful, specially the backreference, but i couldn't get it to work properly in php !!
i use preg_match_all:

    preg_match_all('/__\((\'|")([^\1]+)\1\)/', $text, $matches);

i think that the backreference needs something to work properly inside the range brackets.

Comment: @ahmedhelmy007, I am not a php specialist, but i tried a bit and it seems that you need to escape `'` and `"` so try please this regex. `'/__\((\'|\")([^\1]+)\1\)/'`

Comment: @stema, no, it is not an escaping problem

Comment: any php geek could tell me what is the problem with the backreference here?
in short, i need this to work:
preg_match_all('/__\((\'|")([^\1]+)\1/', "__('match this') . 'not this'", $matches);

Comment: @ahmedhelmy007, only a few people will read your comment here. I would suggest that you submit a new question with this problem. Add also the code how you call the regex, and as tag `php`, I am sure you will get very soon good answers.

Comment: @stema, thanx stema, i have added this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050427/regex-problem-with-backreference-in-pattern-with-preg-match-all

Answer (score 3):

You want to try using non-capturing groups - `(?:ABC)`

Answer (score 2):

- Use `(?:  )` appropriately. These are for grouping that you don't want to capture.
- If you have the quotations inside the capture `(  )`, then the quotes will be included in the capture. If you put the quotes outside, then they will not be included.
- You have more `(  )` than you need. `|` has the least priority in association.
- You are escaping more than you need. Quotations don't need to be escapted.
- Since you are using `[^']` and `[^"]`, you don't have to specify for close quotes/parens.

A fix would be like:

```
'/__\((?:'([^']+)|"([^"]+))/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or make the string inside of the quotes a group.