# regex, problem with backreference in pattern with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, backreference

i wonder what is the problem with the backreference here:

```
preg_match_all('/__\((\'|")([^\1]+)\1/', "__('match this') . 'not this'", $matches);
```

it is expected to match the string between __('') but actually it returns:

```
match this') . 'not this
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do back refs really work in char classes?

Comment: sorry, there is a missing \
i have corrected the battern

Comment: On to the next solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make your regex ungreedy:

```
preg_match_all('/__((\'|")([^\1]+)\1/U', "__('match this') . 'not this'", $matches)
```

Comment: Don't use back refs in char classes.

Comment: And what would you do if a string to match contains escaped quote? Like this: __('match that\'s') . 'not this' :|

Comment: `[^\1]` matches any char but a char with octal value `1`

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a backreference inside a character class because a character class matches exactly one character, and a backreference can potentially match any number of characters, or none.

What you're trying to do requires a negative lookahead, not a negated character class:

```
preg_match_all('/__\(([\'"])(?:(?!\1).)+\1\)/',
    "__('match this') . 'not this'", $matches);
```

I also changed your alternation - `\'|"` - to a character class - `[\'"]` - because it's much more efficient, and I escaped the outer parentheses to make them match literal parentheses.

---

EDIT: I guess I need to expand that "more efficient" remark.  I took the [example](http://regex.info/listing.cgi?ed=3&p=232) Friedl used to demonstrate this point and tested it in RegexBuddy.

Applied to target text `abababdedfg`,
`^[a-g]+$` reports success after three steps, while
`^(?:a|b|c|d|e|f|g)+$` takes 55 steps.

And that's for a *successful* match. When I try it on `abababdedfz`,
`^[a-g]+$` reports failure after 21 steps;
`^(?:a|b|c|d|e|f|g)+$` takes 99 steps.

In this particular case the impact on performance is so trivial it's not even worth mentioning.  I'm just saying whenever you find yourself choosing between a character class and an alternation that both match the same things, you should almost always go with the character class.  Just a rule of thumb.

Comment: "Much more", really? How much more?

Comment: Yes, alternations are very slow, a plague that should be avoided. However, assertions are even slower.

Comment: @sln: That depends on how well the assertion is written and how it's used (just like regexes themselves).  Anyway, the flexibility they provide is well worth the performance hit in most cases.  But there's no excuse for using something like `(a|b|c)` when you can use `[abc]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suprised it didn't give you an unbalance parenthesis error message.

```
 /
   __
   (
       (\'|")
       ([^\1]+)
       \1
 /
```

This `[^\1]` will not take the contents of capture buffer 1 and put it into a character
class. It is the same as all characters that are NOT '1'.

Try this:

`/__\(('|").*?\1\).*/`

You can add an inner capturing parenthesis to just capture whats between quotes:
`/__\(('|")(.*?)\1\).*/`

Edit: If no inner delimeter is allowed, use Qtax regex.
Since, `('|").*?\1` even though non-greedy, will still match all up to the trailing anchor.  In this case `__('all'this'will"match')`, and its better to use `('[^']*'|"[^"]*)`
as

Comment: Technically I think `\1` will be interpreted in a character class as the character with an octal value of 1, but the point is essentially the same nonetheless (i.e. `[^\1]` is not doing what the OP thinks it is). [Example](http://ideone.com/0vQHN).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:
`/__\(("[^"]+"|'[^']+')\)/`

Comment: This would be the preferred method if no inner delimeter is allowed.

Comment: Just to note that the drawback with this method is that its impossible to capture the inner data without the delimeter included.

Comment: @sln: Sure you can capture it; just use a different group for each subpattern: `~__\(("(?<DQ>[^"']+)"|'(?<SQ>[^"']+)')\)~`

Comment: @sln @Alan, or you can use `(?|...)` if your flavor supports it. Eg: `/__\((?|"([^"]+)"|'([^']+)')\)/`. Alan, I wouldn't use `[^"']`, the whole point of different quoting chars is that you can use one inside the other. ;)

Comment: @Alan - I should have said, theres no clean way for an inner capture without post processing logic of the independent capture buffers to determine which one captured.

Comment: @Qtax - Branch reset (if available) is an alternative, however, there are idiosyncracy's across engine's which lead me to be wary of them. Originally saying its impossible, to me though means requiring some platform dependent post processing. Ie: possible caveats.